# Coffeescript: Splat Sum Function

Tags: javascript, recursion, coffeescript

I just got asked this at an interview at Yahoo!: build a `sum` function, that can accept an unlimited amount of arguments (none to infinity), and which will sum all arguments (returns `0` if no arguments passed in).

My solution (wrong), was the following with [coffeescript splats](http://coffeescript.org/#splats):

```
sum = (...) ->
    return 0 if arguments.length < 1
    sum arguments[0] + ...
```

How can I write a coffeescript `sum` function as described above, using splats?

Comment: Apart from the "obvious" (see my answer), what is `sum arguments[0] + ...` supposed to do? Not sure how you want your `sum` function to work. How would you write it without splats (say the function gets an array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the intent of the interview question was to see how you would approach the problem if hand coding it, and these interview questions are always a bit artificial, but...

```
sum = (ary...) ->
  ary.reduce (previous, current, index, array) ->
    previous + current
  , 0

console.log "Sum is: #{sum(1, 4, 6)}"
console.log "Sum is: #{sum()}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to name your splat parameter. "`...`" is not a valid variable name. You seem to want

```
sum = (x, xs...) ->
    if arguments.length < 1
        then 0
        else x + sum xs
```